# ImageButton Rescale and return to original size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

Any idea how this is done? I want to resize the buttons/images bigger when i click it and then back to the regular size when clicked again.

[image: ImageButton on regular display]

[image: Resizes when click, and returns to orignal size when clicked again.]

Comment: the image you are talking about is duck image correct. The duck image you want to rescale or resize correct

Comment: Yup, exactly. Just want to resize from small to big and back.

Comment: I got the solution. Let me know what is the main controller you are shwoing the images. It is list view or static .

Comment: I see in above images that you are showing the four images. Is it static or dynamic content

Comment: Actually it is simpler than that. Just an image button in an activity. I'm not displaying multiple images. I just used the picture as an example.

Comment: So you mean that you have four image button into your layout correct.

Comment: Just one image button.

Comment: The other three images is the same imagebutton background

Comment: I dont quite get it. I just used that as an example.  Im just using 1 image button on my activity.

Comment: Ok I post the answer sure will help you. actually as you told you have single image then. you probably two version of image thumnail and large image. just translate it

Comment: Let me know if you did not get it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a layout file that contains the small and large version of the content that you want to zoom.

The following example creates an ImageButton for clickable image thumbnail and an ImageView that displays the enlarged view of the image:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/thumb1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This initially-hidden ImageView will hold the expanded/zoomed version of
         the images above. Without transformations applied, it takes up the entire
         screen. To achieve the "zoom" animation, this view's bounds are animated
         from the bounds of the thumbnail button above, to its final laid-out
         bounds.
         -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" />

</FrameLayout>
```

> Set up the Zoom Animation

Once you apply your layout, set up the event handlers that trigger the zoom animation. 
The following example adds a View.OnClickListener to the ImageButton to execute the zoom
animation when the user clicks the image button:

```
public class ZoomSampleActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // Hold a reference to the current animator,
    // so that it can be canceled mid-way.
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

    // The system "short" animation time duration, in milliseconds. This
    // duration is ideal for subtle animations or animations that occur
    // very frequently.
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);

        // Hook up clicks on the thumbnail views.

        final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
        thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
            }
        });

        // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
        mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Below the main logic for zooming the imagebutton**

```
private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
    // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
    // immediately and proceed with this one.
    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(
            R.id.expanded_image);
    expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

    // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
    // This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
    // and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container
    // view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
    // bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
    // properties (X, Y).
    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    findViewById(R.id.container)
            .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

    // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
    // bounds using the "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable
    // stretching during the animation. Also calculate the start scaling
    // factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).
    float startScale;
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
            > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
        // Extend start bounds horizontally
        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {
        // Extend start bounds vertically
        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }

    // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
    // begins, it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the
    // thumbnail.
    thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations
    // to the top-left corner of the zoomed-in view (the default
    // is the center of the view).
    expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
    expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

    // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
    // scale properties (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set
            .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                    startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                    startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
            startScale, 1f)).with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                    View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
    });
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;

    // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down
    // to the original bounds and show the thumbnail instead of
    // the expanded image.
    final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
            }

            // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
            // back to their original values.
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.play(ObjectAnimator
                        .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                        View.Y,startBounds.top))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                        View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator
                                .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                        View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
            set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
            set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }
            });
            set.start();
            mCurrentAnimator = set;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'll try this. I didn't expect it to be this complicated.

Comment: Wow, Did you just do this few minutes ago? It worked! Perfectly.

Comment: When i see the problem I know how to handle it. And here I did post. Thank god help you.

Comment: Thank you so much again. :) I'm just starting with android. Hopefully i can return the help you did someday. Still need more practice though. I have a long way, but i'm looking forward to it. I try to research on my own and try to solve my own problems. But there are times when google and even myself can't answer it, so i resort to asking here. :)

Comment: what if i don't set the image in the xml file, instead i set it  inside the activity class?

Comment: Fixed it. :) sorry, hahaha, :)

Comment: So you want to add image view from activity

Comment: Ok no problem keep going.

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable several ways.

Firstly, it can be achieved by using [Shared Element Transitions](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/01/activity-fragment-shared-element-transitions-in-depth-part3a.html). It looks like this is actually just two activities or fragments and the image is the shared element, so it appears as though the image expanded.

You could also do somewhere where when you click on an ImageButton, you remove all elements from the RecyclerView or ListView except the one clicked, and let it resize accordingly.

Comment: I'll take a look at this. :) Thanks. :)